# OSB returns differents results when using a breakpoint in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osb

Weird problem with OSB, while debugging in Eclipse.

If I send a request particular request, OSB returns an error. If I send the same request again, but with a breakpoint in my message flow, suddenly I get a different result.

Anyone has seen this before? It's really messing up my Error handler debugging.

My Error Handler should catch all BEA errors, wich it does when using a breakpoint. But some of them aren't catched if I don't use a breakpoint.

Comment: For more information about how to reproduce the error, please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that because I use the breakpoint, the Eclipse debugger tries to read my $body, which fails because it isn't valid XML, and it then makes an empty $body. Because of this, the following code succeeds. Without a breakpoint, there isn't a $body or a valid $body, and this makes my code fail. I'm now trying to find out how I can work arround this.

Answer (score 0):

@Wesley, we know that it mostly mistake of a developer in such cases. 
Without looking at the code, we can just guess.

```
1. Log $body at every step of message flow and skip breakpoint for better investigation.
2. If you are using javacallout, it is not thread safe by default.
```

Comment: I found out that because I use the breakpoint, the Eclipse debugger tries to read my $body, which fails because it isn't valid XML, and it then makes an empty $body. Because of this, the following code succeeds. Without a breakpoint, there isn't a $body or a valid $body, and this makes my code fail. I'm now trying to find out how I can work arround this.